# Windows Azure REST API Update Role Doesn't Take Effect

Tags: rest, azure

I'm doing some proof of concept work on azure, trying to get a role using the Get Role URL:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roles/<role-name>
```

And then update the role using the Update Role URL:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roleinstances/<role-name>
```

Both of those URLs are straight from the msdn pages. The GET request works and I get XML that matches what I see in the management console.
When I then add an element to the xml and send that back with a PUT on the update URL, I get a 200 response, but I never see the change in the management console. I also don't see any error message when I send gibberish. I'm connecting from C#, and a coworker suggested I could get the response with this:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

But that gets me a 404 error.

Is there an extra step to commit the update? And how can I see the response that msdn mentions?

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

1. When I am just doing quick SMAPI work I use AzureTools (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx).  Specifically, look in the Misc Tools section under "Service Management REST API".  This will show you the full response.
2. To answer your question about how to get the response (txtSMAPIResponse is where AzureTools puts the response info):

   ```
           System.IO.Stream receiveStream;
       System.IO.StreamReader readStream;
       Encoding encode;

       HttpWebResponse response = null;
       try
       {
           response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       }
       catch (WebException ex)
       {
           txtSMAPIRequest.Text = request.Headers.ToString();
           txtSMAPIResponse.Text = ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Response.Headers.ToString();
           try
           {
               receiveStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
               encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
               // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
               readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);
               txtSMAPIResponse.Text += readStream.ReadToEnd();

               // Releases the resources of the response.
               response.Close();
               // Releases the resources of the Stream.
               readStream.Close();
           }
           catch
           {
           }
           return;
       }

       txtSMAPIRequest.Text = request.Method + " " + request.RequestUri + " " + request.ProtocolVersion + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
       txtSMAPIRequest.Text += request.Headers.ToString();
       txtSMAPIResponse.Text = (int)response.StatusCode + " - " + response.StatusDescription + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
       txtSMAPIResponse.Text += response.Headers + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

       receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
       encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
       // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
       readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);
       txtSMAPIResponse.Text += readStream.ReadToEnd();

       // Releases the resources of the response.
       response.Close();
       // Releases the resources of the Stream.
       readStream.Close();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. In my case EndPointACL is not getting updated. Very painful thing is for every update , we have to send the entire ConfigurationSet; There is no way to update the ACL for particular end point.

A typical update looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PersistentVMRole xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ConfigurationSets>
    <ConfigurationSet>
        <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
        <InputEndpoints>
            <InputEndpoint>
                <LocalPort>100</LocalPort>
                <Name>TCP-100</Name>
                <Port>100</Port>
                <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
                <EndpointACL>
            <Rules>
              <Rule>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <Action>deny</Action>
                <RemoteSubnet>108.239.229.0/24</RemoteSubnet>
                <Description>test-rule</Description>
              </Rule>
            </Rules>
          </EndpointACL>
            </InputEndpoint>
        </InputEndpoints>
        <SubnetNames>
            <SubnetName>Subnet-1</SubnetName>
        </SubnetNames>
    </ConfigurationSet>
</ConfigurationSets>
</PersistentVMRole>
```